# How to include a Non DB field in models.py in python?

Tags: python, django-models, model

I am using python.

In my models.py,I have a class like

```
class Users(models.Model): 
   user_id = models.BigIntegerField(primary_key=True) 
   role_id = models.BigIntegerField() 
   user_name = models.CharField(max_length=255) 
   password = models.CharField(max_length=32) 
   last_login_time = models.BigIntegerField(null=False)  

   class Meta: 
       managed = False 
       db_table = 'db_user'
```

In that,I have to add a Non-Db field with a default value.

For Example:

```
class Users(models.Model): 
   user_id = models.BigIntegerField(primary_key=True) 
   role_id = models.BigIntegerField() 
   user_name = models.CharField(max_length=255) 
   password = models.CharField(max_length=32) 
   last_login_time = models.BigIntegerField(null=False) 
 **Id= models.CharField(max_length=2, default='1', editable=False)** 

   class Meta: 
       managed = False 
       db_table = 'db_user'
```

But it throws error like **db_user** does not have **Id** field.

How can I do like this?

Help me with this.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: So `Id` should always be `'1'`?

Comment: What do you mean by "non-db field"? You add it to the DB model, so it will be in the DB. Can you explain what you want to achieve?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem yeah

Comment: @MrBeanBremen I am asking any way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just specify a value at the class level, for example:

```
class Users(models.Model): 
   user_id = models.BigIntegerField(primary_key=True) 
   role_id = models.BigIntegerField() 
   user_name = models.CharField(max_length=255) 
   password = models.CharField(max_length=32) 
   last_login_time = models.BigIntegerField(null=False) 
   Id = '1'

   class Meta: 
       managed = False 
       db_table = 'db_user'
```

Each `Users` object will no have a `myuser.Id` which is equal to `'1'`.